# requirejs multiple page application optimizer merges multiple js files, but still http requests not necessary files

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I have created a multiple pages web applications, including:
 - a single requirejs configuration file, requestjsConfig.js
 - some libraries, like jquery.js, etc... 
 - pages js, like homePage.js
 - the form event binding js, like pageHeader.js
 - common logical handling, like shoppingCart.js

I tried to use r.js to uglify my scripts, and merged into 1 js files. In general, it works, but with a small issues. After compiled, the browser still loads the form binding js files, event they are still merged into the page JS file.

requireJSConfig.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'frontjs/lib',
    paths: {
        eventHandler: '../page/eventHandler',
        feature: '../feature'
    }
});
```

homePage.js

```
requirejs(['../page/requestjsConfig'], function (requestjsConfig) {     
        //requirejs(['feature/page-header', 'feature/common', 'feature/index', 'feature/transport', 'feature/utils']);          
    requirejs(['eventHandler/pageHeader']);                 
});
```

pageHeader.js

```
define(function (require) { 
    var $ = require('jquery');
    require('jquery-cookie');
    require('jquery-storageapi');
    var commonString = require('feature/commonString');
    var shoppingCart = require('feature/shoppingCart');
    ...     
}
```

the build.js for r.js to optimize

```
appDir: '../ecomm',
    mainConfigFile: '../ecomm/frontjs/page/requestjsConfig.js',
    dir: '../ecomm-built',
    modules: [
        //First set up the common build layer.
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl
            name: '../page/requestjsConfig',
            //List common dependencies here. Only need to list
            //top level dependencies, "include" will find
            //nested dependencies.
            include: ['jquery',
                      'jquery.md5'
                     ]
            },
            {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: '../page/homePage',
            include: ['../page/eventHandler/pageHeader'],
            exclude: ['../page/requestjsConfig']
        },
{
            //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
            name: '../page/subCategory',
            include: ['../page/eventHandler/pageHeader'],
            exclude: ['../page/requestjsConfig']
        }
     ]
}
```

After run node tools/r.js -o tools/build.js,
and when access home page, the pageHeader.js is still required.

Comment: according to my testing, all the form binding (page logical) script files which are referenced by requirejs['...',''] will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, thanks everyone, the root cause is path.
In homePage.js, the module is defined as

```
requirejs(['eventHandler/pageHeader']);
```

In build.js,the module is defined as

```
   include: ['../page/eventHandler/pageHeader'],
```